# Applying outbound connection rules PER USER in Windows Firewall with Advanced Security

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, firewall, windows-firewall

In the latest version of the Windows Firewall, included for example in Windows Server 2008 R2, you can block incoming connections and apply this rule only for a set of users (Users Tab in the rule properties).

Why is this not possible for outbound connection rules and how can it be achieved? I need a software solution that blocks all internet access for specific users and for others not and I hope to realize this with the windows firewall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This just isn't a feature that's available. If you want to do something like this, you might look at using Microsoft TMG as an outbound proxy. It can do user/group based access to Internet resources.

Answer (score 5):

This is doable, I just did it for my kid's computers.  Just create the entries below in Task Scheduler.  Note that this is not super-secure, since it doesn't account for things like multiple sessions from remote desktops, etc.  That said, hopefully it will help a lot of people viewing this topic.  Also, note the 30-second delay in Step 2 before the firewall is turned off for registered users.  Not sure if that can be made quicker somehow, 5-10 seconds would be more than enough for my computers.

**Step 1) Create a Task that turns ON the firewall when anyone logs on:**

Task Scheduler -> Action -> "Create Task"

General:

```
 Name:TurnOnWindowsFirewall
 Security Options:"Run whether user is logged on or not" checked
 Security Options:"Run with highest privileges" checked
```

Triggers: (click 'New...')

```
 BeginTheTask:"At log on"
 Settings:"Any User" checked
 Advanced Settings:"Stop if task runs longer than:" checked; "30 minutes" selected
 Advanced Settings:"Enabled" checked
```

Actions: (click 'New...')

```
 Action:"Start a program"
 Program/script:"netsh"
 Add Aruments:"advfirewall set allprofiles state on"
```

Conditions:

```
 Uncheck everything on this tab
```

Settings:

```
 AllowOnDemand: checked
 RunTaskAsSoonAsPossible: checked
 IfTheTaskFails: unchecked
 StopTheTaskIfItRunsLonger: checked; "1 hour" selected
 IfTheRunningTaskDoesNotEndForceIt: checked
 IfTheTaskIsNotSchedAgainDeleteIt: unchecked
 IfTheTaskIsAlreadyRunning: "Do not start a new instance" selected
```

**Step 2) Create a Task that turns OFF the firewall when a certain user logs on:**

Task Scheduler -> Action -> "Create Task"

General:

```
 Name:TurnOffWindowsFirewall
 Security Options:"Run whether user is logged on or not" checked
 Security Options:"Do not store password" checked
 Security Options:"Run with highest privileges" checked
```

Triggers: (click 'New...')

```
 BeginTheTask:"At log on"
 Settings:"Specific User" checked  (select user that should have OPEN internet access.)
 Advanced Settings:"Delay task for:" checked; "30 seconds" selected
 Advanced Settings:"Stop if task runs longer than:" checked; "30 minutes" selected
 Advanced Settings:"Enabled" checked
```

Actions: (click 'New...')

```
 Action:"Start a program"
 Program/script:"netsh"
 Add Aruments:"advfirewall set allprofiles state on"
```

Conditions:

```
 Uncheck everything on this tab
```

Settings:

```
 AllowOnDemand: checked
 RunTaskAsSoonAsPossible: checked
 IfTheTaskFails: unchecked
 StopTheTaskIfItRunsLonger: checked; "1 hour" selected
 IfTheRunningTaskDoesNotEndForceIt: checked
 IfTheTaskIsNotSchedAgainDeleteIt: unchecked
 IfTheTaskIsAlreadyRunning: "Do not start a new instance" selected
```

Good Luck!

Comment: This answer is right what I need just for the same purpose, very helpful, thanks.